# Sunspot gem return all result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot

Sunspot gem return all data like select * from contents

My Model is

```
  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
   searchable do
     text :title
     integer :id
     text :pictures do
       pictures.map { |picture| picture.image_file_name }
     end

   end
```

and my calling section code is

```
    @search =  Contents.search do

         fulltext params[:q].to_s
         fields(:title)
         fields(:image_file_name)
    end


I am looking for filter result which search from multiple fields and multiple tables
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you need to change in the code is the fields attribute that you are trying to search. In the model you have defined the searchable field as:

```
text :pictures do
   pictures.map { |picture| picture.image_file_name }
end
```

Hence, your searchable field is named **pictures**. 
But in the controller search, you are trying to search on the field **image_file_name**, whereas you should be searching on the field **pictures**.

So, your search code needs to look something like this:

```
@search =  Contents.search do

         fulltext params[:q].to_s do
           fields(:title, :pictures) 
         end
end
```

If you still continue facing issues, please also post the code that you are using in the view as well.

Comment: I am using this gem for search by api so i dont have any view section the exact problem is this above code is not filtering any data i checked on console this does the query of select * without any where.

Comment: For getting the result i am using " @search.result" is it correct

Comment: This give me all record and console shows select query without any where

Comment: Can you put in a debugger and see what you are receiving in params